# Site/Page permissions based on FBA roles

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013, fba

I've setup FBA for SharePoint 2013.

I need that only users that have a specific FBA role be able to access to a specific Page.

I tried:

- Adding a FBA role into a Site Group and give permissions to that group in the page.An access denied is the result.
- Adding permissions directly to the FBA role. Same error.

The only way the users are able to access to page is giving permissions directly to them.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Did you find a solution? i already posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604542/fba-user-in-fba-role-is-not-taking-permission-from-sharepoint-group

Comment: I noticed a weird behavior on that. I had to sign out and sign in with the fba user involved and it finally takes the changes. Please let me know if you find a better solution for that.